# A simple Service that never stop. Why?

Tags: android, android-service

I am developing a very simple app that play a song forever until the user stop it.
I am using the bind/unbind service functions just to send a simple message ( hello ) from the activity to the service.

The problem is that when I tap to stop the song, it doesn't stop ( even if in the Logcat I see the "stop" string ). Why ?

This is my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean started = false;
    boolean musicBound = false;
    TextView button;

    private Intent playIntent;
    private PlayerService musicSrv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playstopbutton);

        playIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // put your code here...
        if(!started) {
          //  button.setText(">");
        }else{
          //  button.setText("||");
        }

    }

    //connect to the service
    private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.i("My App", "conn");
            PlayerService.MusicBinder binder = (PlayerService.MusicBinder)service;
            //get service
            musicSrv = binder.getService();
            //pass list
            musicSrv.tryit("hello");
            musicBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.i("My App", "disc");
            musicBound = false;
        }
    };

    public void playstop(View v)
    {
        if(!started) {
            Log.i("My App", "start");
            started = true;
          //  button.setText("||");
            bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(playIntent);
        }else{
            Log.i("My App", "stop");
            started = false;
          //  button.setText(">");
            stopService(playIntent);
            musicSrv=null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        if (musicConnection != null) {
            unbindService(musicConnection);
        }

        stopService(playIntent);
        musicSrv=null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**PlayerService:**

```
public class PlayerService extends Service
{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    String title = "aaaa";
    String msg = "bbbb";
    String ticker = "just a ticker";

    private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.note2)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setTicker(ticker).setColor(0xff222222).build();



        startForeground(11, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    //binder
    public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
        PlayerService getService() {
            return PlayerService.this;
        }
    }

    //activity will bind to service
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return musicBind;
    }

    //release resources when unbind
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        return false;
    }

    public void tryit(String stringa){
       Log.i("My App", stringa);

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
        stopForeground(true);
        Log.i("PROVA SERVICE", "Distruzione Service");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> when I tap to stop the song, it doesn't stop

Because you are only calling `stop()` on the `MediaPlayer` if either:

- the client unbinds from it (`onUnbind()`), which is not what your client is doing, or
- the client unbinds from it *and* you stop it (`onDestroy()`), which is not what your client is doing

A service will be destroyed when both of the following statements are true:

- Each client that had bound to is unbinds, and
- If `startService()` had been called for this service, `stopService()` is called

In this case, you are calling `stopService()`, but you are still bound to the service, so `onDestroy()` is not called.

Comment: I have just added unbindService(musicConnection); function after stopService() but I get an error ( java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service... )

Comment: @xRobot since you don't call startService (just bind), you don't need to call stopService at all-  just unbind.  But I don't think this code is architected the way you want anyway-  pressing play a 2nd time after that won't work because you're unbound.  You need to separate the idea of starting and stopping the music from the service.

Comment: @GabeSechan just edited the code, now it works the 2nd time. The error was caused from "        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }" in onDestroy method. So I have removed it. But why ?